# strcmp cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*

Tags: c++, strcmp

Apologies in advance for the elementary nature of the question.

I am trying to use the `strcmp` function to test two strings for matching characters.

I reduced the issue to the simple code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> 

using namespace std;

void compareStrings(string, string);

int main()
{
    string string1 = "testString", string2 = "testString";
    compareStrings(string1, string2);
    return 0;
}

void compareStrings(string stringOne, string stringTwo)
{
    if (strcmp(stringOne,stringTwo) == 0)
        cout << "The strings match." << endl;
    else 
        cout << "The strings don't match." << endl;
}
```

Could someone explain the following compiler error message?

```
./newProgram.cpp: In function ‘void compareStrings(std::string, std::string)’:
./newProgram.cpp:17:32: error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int strcmp(const char*, const char*)’
  if (strcmp(stringOne,stringTwo) == 0)
                                ^
```

Thanks!
Xz.

Comment: Why are you using `strcmp` with C++ strings?

Answer (score 12):

`strcmp` is for C strings (null-terminated `char *`).  `string::compare` is for C++ `string`s.

If you *really* want to use `strcmp` with your `std::string`, you can use [`string::c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) to get a pointer to the underlying C-string:

```
if (strcmp(stringOne.c_str(), stringTwo.c_str()) == 0)
```

But of course, if you're using C++, you should actually *use* C++, and make use of [`std::string`'s `==` overload](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/).

```
if (stringOne == stringTwo)
```